# automatically share photos to Photos iCloud Shared Albums

Tags: macos, applescript, photos, automator, photos.app

I'd like to script the Yosemite Photos app so that every time I place images to a folder on my desktop, it automatically is imported into the Photos app and uploaded to a shared album. Is this possible?